# Solr Reverse WildCard & Field Association

Tags: solr

I have been using Solr for a while now, just strike me that I have  Reverse WildCard Filter declared but without any field being declared/associated to the type 'textReverse'& no copy field to copy the values into either. Yet search with leading wildcards works !

Wouldn't it be norm have the field type as 'textReverse' to enable leading wildcard searches ?

Just by having this declaration works,

```xml
<fieldType name="textReverse" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true" maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

without having to actually declare a field of that type, for instance,

```xml
<field name="fooColumn" type="textReverse" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

but I do have 'fooColumn' as type 'text' ( field type without the reverse wildcard filter.. )

is there a gap in understanding ?

Answer (score 2):

`ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` enables **faster** leading wildcard queries - such queries will work just fine even without this filter. You can confirm this by removing the field type declaration from your config and then firing a few queries with leading wildcards.

Take a look at the description of solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory  [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory).  If you start using this filter, then the performance of queries with leading wildcards should improve a lot.

Comment: thx for replying, I tried removing the fieldType. leading WildCard searched fails completely, **HTTP Status 400 - org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse '*duluth*': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery** . It goes back to my original question how by just having field type declaration without having fields of that type, enables leading wildcard search for those fields that are not of that type ?

Comment: This is very surprising - are you sure that nothing else was changed in the config?  It may help if you could post your `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml`.

Comment: nothing changed except disabling field type schema.xml [link](http://pastebin.com/Nzvi3pT3)  solconfig.xml [link](http://pastebin.com/DEQgc11C)  Solr Ver:3.5.0

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what the issue is. You could try to reindex and check the behavior. Also, please keep in mind that the default query parser `dismax` does not support wildcards and we need to use `edismax`.